# Trying to append dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, append

I am trying to create then append a dictionary but I am getting the following error I can't solve: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String: AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance!

```
    var parameters: [String:[String:AnyObject]] = [
        "user": [
            "email": email,
            "password": passwordTextField.text,
            "first_name": firstName,
            "last_name": lastName
        ]
    ]

    parameters["user"]["status"] = "Connected"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you retreive from a `Dictionary` may or may not exist, hence its return value is optional. 
if you are 100% certain, the returned value is not `nil`, use `!`, otherwise either check for `nil` or use `?` (As pointed out by Lucian Boboc)

In your code, try replacing with the following.

```
parameters["users"]!["status"] = "Connected"
```

Comment: That is because the return value is optional, if you are 100% the returned value is not nil, use "!", otherwise, use "?"

Answer (score 2):

`parameters["user"]` is an optional so you have to unwrap the optional explicitly, since you know the value exists.

```
parameters["user"]!["status"] = "Connected"
```